# Is it possible to define the type of a method argument to be a class or any derivate class?

Tags: c++, oop

Let's say we have:

```
class Base {...}
class A : public Base {...}
class B : public Base {...}
```

Is it possible to set as argument type of a generic method:

```
myMethod([typei'mlookingfor] c) {}
```

so that I can pass Base, A and B to `myMethod()` without overloading the method?
and also make it work with references and pointers?

Comment: Please look up C++ template programming. Thank you.

Comment: @rwong, with templates `myMethod()` will work also with primitive types and I don't want that.

Comment: @Jeffrey not so, you can use type_traits for determine that T is derived from some base.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Pertinent link: [How many C++ Programmers does it take to replace a light bulb?](http://www.cyprich.com/2007/08/17/how-many-c-programmers-does-it-take-to-change-a-lightbulb/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a pointer or a reference to the base class works for you, just use that:

```
void myMethod(Base& c) {}
A a;
B b;
myMethod(a);  //OK
myMethod(b);  //OK
```

Note that you'll have to use references or pointers to prevent **object slicing**. If the method is `myMethod(Base c)`, you'll lose type information of derived objects.

If not, you can use a template

```
template<typename T>
void myMethod(T& c)
{
}
A a;
B b;
myMethod(a);
myMethod(b);
```

Comment: @Jeffrey meaning you could possibly want to use specific derived class methods, in which case you'd have to do some casting.

Comment: Last question: what does exactly happens inside? If I pass `A` to `myMethod(Base c)` is there a conversion? And what if I pass `A*` to `myMethod(Base* c)`?

Comment: Yes, in the first case (`Base c`) the object is converted to `Base`. In the second one, you have a pointer to `Base`, but the object it points to is still an `A`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore If you want to use specific derived class methods, you generally shouldn't make the method accept the base class as an argument, you're abusing OO. When you use the pointer or reference method, the object retains its identity as the derived class. You can only call methods defined in the base class, but if they're overridden in a derived class the overriding method will be used.

Answer (score 3):

Q: Is it possible to define the type of a method argument to be a class or any derivate class?

A: Sure.  Why not?

If you want a "generic" parameter that can be any arbitrary type, just use a template.

Otherwise, if you want "class or any subclass", just use the base class.

Useful quote:

> http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_are_the_concepts_of_object_oriented_programming
>
> ***Polymorphism*** allows the programmer to treat derived class members just
>   like their parent class' members. More precisely, Polymorphism in
>   object-oriented programming is the ability of objects belonging to
>   different data types to respond to method calls of methods of the same
>   name, each one according to an appropriate type-specific behavior.

Which, I believe, is exactly what you're looking for :)

Comment: Constructive answers, please.

Comment: @Jeffrey: if you simply want to be able to handle class "Base" (or any subclass of "Base") - yes.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways how to do this.  1st is dynamic polymorphism. Works only with pointers and refs. There is small run time overhead:

```
void myMethod(Base& x) { ...}
```

2nd - static polymofism:

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if<is_base_of<Base,T>::value>
myMethod(base x) {...}
```